# Value error with labelencoder and OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-mining, data-analysis

I'm trying to turn a categorical string column into several dummy variable binary columns, but I'm getting a valueerror.

Here's the code:

```
import sys, os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser
import math
import traceback
import logging
datasetMod = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

X = datasetMod.iloc[:, 3:6].values
y = datasetMod.iloc[:, 1].values
print(X[:, 0])

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
try:
    labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
    X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
    onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
    X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
except Exception as e:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
```

Here's the error:

```
<class 'ValueError'> multipleLinearRegression.py 23
```

The result from that print statement of that column is:

```
['Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Weekend' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday'
 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Workday' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend'
 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend' 'Weekend']
```

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the strings themselves, no whitespaces inbetween, no numeric like notation. So I don't understand why i'm getting a valuetype can't convert string to float error.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Update**

The onehotencoder works somewhat fine now, but the final result is of type object, while it's supposed to be of type float64:

```
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 3])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1,2,3])
onehotencoder.fit(X[:, 1])
onehotencoder.fit(X[:, 2])
onehotencoder.fit(X[:, 3])
onehotencoder.transform(X[:, 1])
onehotencoder.transform(X[:, 2])
onehotencoder.transform(X[:, 3])
X = onehotencoder.toArray()
```

**Update 2**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 3])

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1,2,3])
X[:, 1] = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 1]).toarray()
X[:, 2] = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 2]).toarray()
X[:, 3] = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 3]).toarray()

print(X.dtype) #object
```

**Final Code**

Since the `categorical_features` already dictates the indexes, i can fit_transform() on the whole matrix `X`. Thanks to @mkos for the patience!

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 3])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1,2,3])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X)
```

Comment: try `le.fit(X[:, 0].unique())` then`le.transform(X[:, 0])`

Comment: i separated them like you suggested, and its onehotencoder.fit(X[:, 0].unique()) that's causing the error

Comment: actually, if i remove unique() it works, just with a deprecation warning "Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

Comment: `le` mean `LabelEncoder` this need `unique`;`OneHotEncoder` do not need

Comment: that gives it a valuetypeerror again

Comment: I think the label encoder is working fine, but X is still an object array, while it's supposed to be a float64, which is the defeault format of onehotencoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1,2,3])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X)
```

you can print it with:

```
print(X.toArray())
```

Having `X` as a sparse matrix is not bad, because it saves memory. If you want to see it, then you convert it to regular `np.array` with `toArray()`.

Comment: Cheers, how do I get it to be of type float64? It's still defaulting to type object.(X I mean)

Comment: ye, still results in type object

Comment: hmm, if i don't add a .toarray() at the end of the onehotencoder fit_transform(), then my values become : "   <1x284 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 146 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

Comment: how exactly are you checking for type, if I may ask?

Comment: Variable explorer in spyder

Comment: Can you `print(X.dtype)` and paste the output?

Comment: the output is: object

Comment: stupid of me, this is bad >> `X = onehotencoder.toArray() ` you can't do it. You already did the assignment doing `fit_transform()` with `X[:, 1] = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 1])`. Remove that line and you should be good.

Comment: sorry, I have, i updated the code(update 2) with what I have now